# Problems when trying to pipe out colors in bash

Tags: bash, sed, colors, echo

I'm a bit lost on why I need all those backslashes for this to print "Hello World" with the correct colors.

```
xxx@yyy:/tmp$ echo $Red
\033[0;34m
xxx@yyy:/tmp$ echo $Red
\033[0;31m    xxx@yyy:/tmp$ echo -e "Hello ${Red} World" | sed "s/^/\\\\\\${Blue}/g" | xargs echo -e
Hello  World
```

What's the reason for that? Is there any other easier way to sed the colors into the original echo? I'll be needing to do something similar, where I take some text files and I'll try to punch in colors before viewing it in the console.

Thanks

Comment: Backslashes are both string escapes and regexp escapes. So you need to multiply them so that `sed` will output them literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to combine the color codes and the text to be output into the same `echo` command if all you are doing is coloring the entirety of the text at once:

```
red="$(echo -e "\033[0;31m")"
reset="$(echo -e "\033[0m")"
echo "$red"
echo "This text is red."
echo "$reset"
```

If you're trying to change embedded color codes; you similarly don't need to rip out the entire escape sequence.  To change red text to yellow, you can:

```
echo "$color_festooned_text" | sed 's/;31/;33/g'
```

Comment: I need to color arbitrary pieces of text (for instance, any IP in a log file). Would this serve that purpose?

Comment: You can use `sed` once you have your coloring definitions done with things like `sed "s/some_expression/$red&$reset/"`.  For example, this will turn all vowels red:  `sed "s/[aeiou]/$red&$reset/g"`.

Comment: One last question. As this will be used to pipe through large amounts of text, some of it shown in real-time, wouldn't this method have a serious impact on performance? We're pretty much several times per line spawning a new shell.

Comment: If you build one large `sed` script to perform all of your substitutions and insertions, you will only be spawning one process per line.